# ChatPDF with OpenChatKit

Tags: python, huggingface

I want to create a program similat to https://www.chatpdf.com/ but using the open source model https://github.com/togethercomputer/OpenChatKit. I saw that with OpenChatKit you cna use the --retrieval to reply with information from wikipedia. How would you replace the index from wikipedia with your own index from some pdf files?